# Can I rename the 'name/nickname' of the cloned remote repository?

Tags: git

I've watched a tutorial on how to add a remote repository and followed along it.

```
git remote add origin http:.........
```

I thought the `origin` is a git command and followed it.

Later on that day I found out that it is the name/nickname? for the remote repo.

Can I rename it? So I could be pushing like this `git push myproject master`

Comment: wait I must have messed up my question let me edit it

Comment: @Biffen sorry, what I meant was git add remote

Comment: I assume you mean `git remote add ...`. Anyway, `origin` is the common name for the default/only remote. But you can rename it as much as you like.

Comment: Note that when using `git clone`, you can specify a name to use in place of `origin`: `git clone -o beeblebrox <url>` will call it `beeblebrox`. There's no good reason to do this: you'll just confuse everyone, possibly including yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename a remote with [`git remote rename`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emrenameem).